# Connection Between External Application and Revit?

Tags: c#, desktop-application, software-design, revit-api, autodesk

How can an External Application interact with Revit(with the help of commands from an application) and there should be a transfer of input/output?

Can we implement it from any of the workaround?

If yes, then for how long will this workaround succeed ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any kind of interprocess communication that you like. No workarounds are needed. It will work forever. Just keep in mind that the Revit API is entirely event driven. The Building Coder provides more details on [External Events for Modeless Access and Driving Revit from Outside](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.28).